# views.py and urls.py do not connect to perform a function

Tags: python, mysql, django

I have a mysql database connected to django, I know it is connected because you already showed me data. However I made a small form to do tests and does not save the data. The code is correct because I already moved it from place to `def index (request):` and there if you send me the data what is not because it does not enter correctly in the function that I did

views.py

```py
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from models import Test

def index(request):
    test = Test.objects.all()
    context = {'test': test }

    return render(request, 'test_app/index.html', context)


def create(request):
    print request.POST  
    test = Test(name=request.POST['name'], breed= request.POST['breed'])
    test.save()
    return redirect('/')
```

urls.py

```py
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index),
    url(r'^create/$', views.create)

]
```

index.html

```html
 <form action"/create" method="post">
      {% csrf_token %}
      <label for="name">Name: <input type="text" name="name" />
    </label>
      <label for="breed">Breed: <input type="text" name="breed"/> 
    </label> <input type="submit" value="create" />

    </form>
```

I do not have an error just do not save in the database, in the console if you send a `POST` but without any variable. Use python 2.7 and django 1.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand your question, but it looks to me like your problem is that your form is submitting to the wrong url. Your form points to `/create` and your url pattern is `r'^create/$'`.

To make the form submit to your create view, either set the regex to optionally match the trailing slash `r'^create/?$'`, or add the trailing slash to your form action, `action="/create/"`.